# Getting attr of an option in jQuery

Tags: jquery, attr

I have a form like this:

```
<select name="category" id="cat">
<option value="cat1" id="hello">Category1</option>
<option value="cat2" id="hello2">Category2</option>
</select>
```

if i use `$('#cat').val()` with change function in #cat id , it displays values(cat1 or cat2).

i want to learn how can i get id or Category1(or Category2) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#cat option:selected').attr('id');
```

the selector [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) will return the selected option in a select element, or an array in case of `multiple="multiple"`

Comment: Thank you this is exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').change(function() {
    alert($('option:selected',this).attr('id')); 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/each/kqb9S/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```js
$('#cat').on('change', function() {
  alert( $(this).children('option:selected').attr('id') )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="category" id="cat">
  <option value="cat1" id="hello">Category1</option>
  <option value="cat2" id="hello2">Category2</option>
</select>
```